# The most accurate way to determining the arrival time of an ethernet frame in a c program

Tags: c, networking, ethernet

I am using the c program available [here](https://gist.github.com/austinmarton/2862515) to receive Ethernet frames. I would like to know the exact arrival time of the frame and print it. Is the arrival time available as field in one of the networking structs that the program uses or how would deduce the arrival time of the frame?

Comment: Post relevant code and information  here to add clarity to the question.

Comment: @chux I cannot post the code as it is too large (it won't allow me) but I have provided the link. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no "arrival time" attached to the frames obtained via the standard socket API calls.  Depending on the timing resolution you require, you could just call `clock_gettime()` immediately after your `recv()` call succeeds to get an estimate.

Beware that this will not be the frame arrival time at the physical layer, but rather the time your process received it.  So if it had been sitting in a driver buffer before your process retrieved it, the time could be different.  And it is also subject to scheduling delays and other factors, so it could be off by hundreds of microseconds, possibly substantially more depending on system load.

Also be aware that *printing the time also takes time* that would otherwise be spent servicing the buffer.  Packets can arrive via Ethernet much faster than they can be printed on a console.  The act of printing the arrival time could entirely disrupt your future arrival time estimates if not done properly.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to explain that, I appreciate it. Is there a way, do you know, how to get the arrival time at the physical layer or at the closest?